# Redirect among views in Sencha Touch app

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a list in Sencha Touch app and in this redirection is not working correctly..

```
  redirectToSurveyEditionView: function (item, record) {
    var templateName = record.data.templateName,
      customerAddress = record.data.customerAddress;
    this.redirectTo(Ext.String.format(Survey.util.Settings.getRoute('surveyEdition'), templateName, customerAddress));
  },
```

and my routes:

```
routes          : {
 'surveys/:customerId/openSurveys': 'initViewController'
},
```

Only works in the first row.. what am I doing wrong?

If I debug I can see correctly templateName and customerAddress and is detecting the event (I am putting a console.log() for example), but when I tap on the row is not working..

Comment: Can you please explain what should happen and what is not happening? Also what are your routes configuration and share that code too.

Comment: I have added new code in the post..